# What is the origin of the common bell chime motif?

Tags: identify-this-song

There is an 8-note motif that is used by the chimes on bell towers, clocks and doorbells throughout the western world.

It is A-F-G-C, C-G-A-F then repeated. 
It can be hard at the beginning of Miles Davis version of the song "If I Were A Bell" from Guys and Dolls.

What is the origin of this motif?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I thought I knew the answer to this - but a bit of research showed me I was only half right.

I'd have said that the clock tower of the Palace of Westminster, the UK's Parliamentary building, was the origin. However, it appears I'm wrong - it was the trigger for its popularity but not its origin.

The set of tunes is, though, known as the **Westminster Quarters**.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Westminster_Quarters) helped me out -

> This chime is traditionally, though without substantiation, believed
>   to be a set of variations on the four notes that make up the fifth and
>   sixth measures of "I know that my Redeemer liveth" from Handel's
>   Messiah.[2] This is why the chime is also played by the bells of the
>   so-called 'Red Tower' in Halle, the native town of Handel. It was
>   written in 1793 for a new clock in St Mary the Great, the University
>   Church in Cambridge. There is some doubt over exactly who composed it:
>   Revd Dr Joseph Jowett, Regius Professor of Civil Law, was given the
>   job, but he was probably assisted by either Dr John Randall (1715–99),
>   who was the Professor of Music from 1755, or his brilliant
>   undergraduate pupil, William Crotch (1775-1847).
>
> In the mid-19th century the chime was adopted by the clock tower at
>   the Palace of Westminster (where Big Ben hangs), whence its fame
>   spread. It is now possibly the most commonly used chime for striking
>   clocks.

Incidental information - the clock is not called Big Ben, the bell that chimes the hours is Big Ben, the clock is just the clock of the Palace of Westminster & actually doesn't really have a name.